# How to enable one cell to editable in ag grid angular once we enter in other cell

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, tablecelleditor

I have two columns in ag grid angular. In those first one cell is enable to edit, if user enters a single letter in that cell then automatically the other cell has to enable for edit. Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function into the second column's cell editor's CellEditorParams, that tells it whether or not the cell should be editable, based on the value of the cell in the first column.

That second cell editor, can, if the cell should not be editable, return `true` from the `isCancelBeforeStart()` method, to keep editing from starting in that cell.